# Collection View flow layout with zoom effect and three items visible

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, slider, flowlayout

This question might be marked as not well asked, but better thy.

I am trying to find a solution on how to create a collection view in Xamarin.iOS with three items visible one centered and two on both sides partially visible left and right. Something like this https://github.com/lukagabric/LGLinearFlow. I found many swift and objective c implementations but nothing for Xamarin.iOS.

The closest i found was using custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout in the documentation under section Subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview but is not defined how to use it.

Do you know some implementation or how to implement it in Xamarin.iOS Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you post, this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview has told us how to implement the flowLayout. We just need to initialize a `UICollectionView` with this flow layout.

**Construct a new Collection View**:

```
LineLayout lineLayout = new LineLayout();

UICollectionView collectionView = new UICollectionView(View.Bounds, lineLayout);
View.AddSubview(collectionView);
collectionView.DataSource = new MyCollectionViewSource();
collectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(UINib.FromName("MyCollectionViewCell", null), "Cell");
```

**Then its dataSource can be like this**:

```
public class MyCollectionViewSource : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        MyCollectionViewCell cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell", indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell;

        cell.MyStr = "label" + indexPath.Row;

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return 20;
    }       
}
```

Please notice that the constant in the `LineLayout` can be adjusted to fit your requirement. And the `SectionInset` means the distance between each section, we should adjust this to ensure that CollectionView has only one row.

I made a sample [here](https://github.com/landl0526/CustomCollectionView.git) for you referring to.

Comment: There is one problem with this solution the first and the last elements are not reachable. But can be easily fixed.